# Can any one suggest me what is the valid process for Issuing Token in ICO

Tags: transactions, ethereum

Can anyone suggest me what is the valid process for Issuing Token in ICO? Actually, I have seen some ICO that send Tokens after some delay (some time 48 hrs). I just want to know that what is the valid process for issuing Tokens. I mean whether I will do this manually after checking my Wallet or Write a Smart contract in such a way that transfer Token as soon as transection completed by end user.